# what are the unique sound patterns i can explore

Tags: theory, chords, scales

beside the seven modes in any key,

and common chord progressions(1-4-5,2-5-1,6-2-1 ..etc)

and arpeggios (minor, major, ...etc)

and scales (harmonic minor, altered ...etc)

what are the other generic patterns that have a distinctive sound that i should be exploring ?
or is that all that theory provides us with, and the rest is mix and match and creative work based on those tools ?

Comment: Are you asking what constitutes the *rest* of music theory besides the things you listed? Because there is a **lot** more than just the few things in your question.

Comment: to some extent yes, I'm asking "what tools does music theory provides in terms of uniquely sounding patterns"

Comment: The answer(s) to that question are too many and too large. For one thing you left out rhythm completely. I mean you've barely listed what could be contained in the first three chapters of a basic music theory book. How much theory have you studied? If you haven't taken at least four semesters/two years of college level music theory then you haven't even begun to start.

Comment: I'm asking specifically about general usage patterns, not the whole of music theory, just the titles of the chapters if you'd call them so, and no i didn't study music, and i can't afford so

Comment: You might as well ask, "In addition to the laws of thermodynamics, what other important laws of physics are there?" Or, "I know about haiku and limericks. What other forms of creative writing could I explore?" You suggest you would be satisfied with "the titles of the chapters", but the chapters from which books? All of music theory would (and does) fill a small library! There are thousands of chapter titles!

Comment: how I'm supposed to know that before asking ?

Comment: Even if you "cant afford to study music", this should keep you occupied for a few years. Most of the sections include more links, including "book-sized" websites. http://www.dolmetsch.com/theoryintro.htm

Comment: If you approach music theory as something to provide you recipes and rules to follow, you may be disappointed. If you approach it to find ways to think about music that will help you systemise and understand your own rules and recipes, it may be more useful.

Comment: i think of it as more of hints into what might work, and how i should approach it

Comment: Yep - that sounds healthy. But each 'hint' can translate into many possibilities. Ultimately though you need to take inspiration from what inspires you on a given day. It could be a theory book, it could be an oldies radio station, it could be Brian Eno's *oblique strategies*....

Comment: What is your purpose of asking?  Where do you want the answers to go?  As the comments here have pointed out, there is a vast volume of material in music theory.  So vast that we have a Stack Exchange for it!  What do you intend to do with an answer once given?

Comment: an answer would be a reasonable list of generic patterns that theory explains, not a reference just the title of the concept, my goal was seeking distinctive sounds for example arpeggios are such a patterns that provide distinctive sounds

Comment: It will be dependent on what's included in your 'etc'.

Comment: It sounds like you are, like many "internet guitarists" falling down the enticing trap of thinking that first you learn music theory, and then you'll find interesting sounds to make. It's really the other way round: you should find things that sound great or interesting to you, and then try and use theory to find out why they sound the way they do. Go and listen to a diverse range of music, learn to play it, find the parts that interest you most, and then come back with questions about why the parts that interest you sound the way they do. Then you'll be on the way to growing your sound.

Comment: I'm saying "explore" not use as a basis, using internet guitarist like that is degratory, i never had the chance to study music formally, and only guitar is an affordable instrument for a third world african, also, i listen to different genres and learn licks and riffs from, learn chord progressions and i always try to analyse the melodies, but i feel my knowledge is lacking severely, I'm looking for more groupings/patterns/intervalic structures.. that i can explore through new ways of making melody/harmony, an example of such things as i said early are arpeggios or the modes of the key